# How can I get ESLint to recognize Docusaurus aliases?

Tags: node.js, eslint, docusaurus

### The Situation

I'm working on a [Docusaurus](https://docusaurus.io/) project which will include some custom components.  I'd like to also use [ESLint](https://eslint.org/), and in particular the [AirBnB](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-config-airbnb) config.

When I run the linter on the initially generated Docusaurus project I get a few errors (not unexpected), but these three give me pause:

```
src/pages/index.jsx
  3:20  error  Unable to resolve path to module '@theme/Layout'                     import/no-unresolved
  4:18  error  Unable to resolve path to module '@docusaurus/Link'                  import/no-unresolved
  5:34  error  Unable to resolve path to module '@docusaurus/useDocusaurusContext'  import/no-unresolved
```

I suspect these modules are aliases that Docusaurus knows how to resolve, but ESLint doesn't.

### The Question

I would like to avoid disabling `import/no-unresolved`.

Is there a handy way for me to get ESLint to recognize (and resolve) the aliases that come from Docusaurus?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@theme`, `@docusaurus`, etc aren't actual paths. They are webpack aliases. To prevent ESLint from tripping up on those, you could ignore those in the ESLint settings

```
"import/no-unresolved": [ 2, {"ignore": ["^@theme", "^@docusaurus", "^@site"]}],
```

Comment: This is not working for me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73102535/eslint-not-recognising-docusaurus-aliases-when-using-typescript