# ESLint not recognising Docusaurus aliases when using Typescript?

Tags: typescript, eslint, docusaurus

I'm working on a Docusaurus project running TypeScript/ESLint. More specifically, I have the rule:

```js
{
  'import/no-unresolved': 'error',
}
```

I have got the setup:

```json
 "devDependencies": {
    "@docusaurus/module-type-aliases": "...",
    "@tsconfig/docusaurus": "...",
    "typescript": "..."
  }
```

and my `tsconfig.json` extends the Docusaurus TS config:

```json
 "extends": "@tsconfig/docusaurus/tsconfig.json"
```

When I run the linter I get a few errors:

```js
  2:18  error  Unable to resolve path to module '@docusaurus/Head'         import/no-unresolved
  3:25  error  Unable to resolve path to module '@docusaurus/BrowserOnly'  import/no-unresolved
  5:20  error  Unable to resolve path to module '@theme/Layout'            import/no-unresolved
```

I suspect these modules are aliases that Docusaurus knows how to resolve, but ESLint doesn't. When I `cmd + click` on the import, it takes me to the declared module.

[I found a proposed solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70089592/8023887) but this does not seem to fix my issue:

```json
  settings: {
    'import/no-unresolved': [
      2,
      { ignore: ['^@theme', '^@docusaurus', '^@site'] },
    ],
  }
```

It could be purely a regex thing? I cannot find anything else on the internet regarding this niche issue so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is that you are adding it to the settings portion of the eslintrc. you need to add the snippit to your rules section:

```js
 rules: {
    "import/no-unresolved": [
      2,
      { ignore: ["^@theme", "^@docusaurus", "^@site"] },
    ],
```

works for me.